# Implement fmt::Display for Vec<T>

Tags: printf, rust, traits

I want to implement the `fmt::Display` for a nested struct commonly used in my code.

```
// The root structure
pub struct WhisperFile<'a> {
    pub path: &'a str,
    pub handle: RefCell<File>,
    pub header: Header
}

pub struct Header{
    pub metadata: metadata::Metadata,
    pub archive_infos: Vec<archive_info::ArchiveInfo>
}

pub struct Metadata {
   // SNIP
}

pub struct ArchiveInfo {
   // SNIP
}
```

As you can see, this is a non-trivial tree of data. The `archive_infos` property on `Header` can be quite long when presented as one line.

I would like to emit something along the lines of

```
WhisperFile ({PATH})
  Metadata
    ...
  ArchiveInfo (0)
    ...
  ArchiveInfo (N)
    ...
```

But when I try to display `Vec<ArchiveInfo>` I get that Display is not implemented. I can implement `fmt::Display` for `ArchiveInfo` but that's not enough since `fmt::Display` is not implemented for the parent container `Vec`. If I implement fmt::Display for `collections::vec::Vec<ArchiveInfo>` I get `the impl does not reference any types defined in this crate; only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types`.

I have tried iterating over the vec and calling `write!()` but I couldn't figure out what the control flow should look like. I think `write!()` needs to be return value of the function but that breaks down with multiple calls.

How can I pretty print a Vec of my structures?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As this error states, you **cannot** implement a trait for a type you don't own:

> the impl does not reference any types defined in this crate; only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types

However, you can implement `Display` for your wrapper type. The piece you are missing is to use the [`try!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.try.html) macro or the try operator `?`:

```
use std::fmt;

struct Foo(Vec<u8>);

impl fmt::Display for Foo {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Values:\n")?;
        for v in &self.0 {
            write!(f, "\t{}", v)?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let f = Foo(vec![42]);
    println!("{}", f);
}
```

Comment: *the impl does not reference any types defined in this crate* => still, in this case, the wording is confusing; `Vec<ArchiveInfo>` does reference a type defined in this crate after all.

Comment: I am not familiar with the `&self.0` bit. Looks like your structure is positional so I suppose it does a positional lookup?

Comment: @xrl oh yes, sorry. You can have a `tuple struct` where the struct members are anonymous, but available positionally (`.0`, `.1`, ...). When it is a single member, it's called a *newtype*, which is a nice way of wrapping your own semantics around an existing type.

Comment: An irrelevant question here, struct Foo(Vec<u8>); what is this syntax (of parenthesis)?

Comment: @Sajuuk https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#using-tuple-structs-without-named-fields-to-create-different-types

Comment: Here's the precise *orphan rule*: https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/items/implementations.html#orphan-rules